# Need help with PHP GD imagesetpixel()

Tags: php, image, gd, pixel

```
$imageurl = "kaptka.gif";
$im = imagecreatefromgif($imageurl);
$b = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagesetpixel($im, 5, 5, $b);

header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($im, "asd.gif");
```

kaptka.gif is normal gif image. I want to draw some pixels anywhere on the image. Asd.gif looks normal, but when i open the file it should show me both like asd.gif, but it shows just "IMAGE" text.

Comment: `Asd.gif looks normal, but when i open the file it should show me both like asd.gif, but it shows just "IMAGE" text.` Is extremely unclear. You say it looks normal until you open it and it doesn't look right. Please fix your question.

Comment: Asd.gif looks normal when i save it to the server, but idk why it can't be shown by imagegif($im);

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function `imagegif()` with a filename. This will write the image to disc. To display the contents, simply call it without the filename: this will pass the contents to the output stream, which means it will be sent to the client's browser. One way to do both is to call it twice, once to save the file, and once to display it.

When saving the file, you can assign the result to a variable `$foo=imagegif($im, 'bar.gif')` and then check the result to see if the save was successful. A FALSE means it failed.

You say the image saved to the server is OK, so the reason you are getting an "IMAGE text" in your browser is probably because you are sending a PNG header, but no data (because of the way you called `imagefig()`).

Comment: No. I'm doing imagegif($im); and the same. Maybe you could write a script which could use imagesetpixel and imagegif ?